# Convert number of rows by condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to convert number of rows by condition:

```
df.loc[df['file'] ==  '0.mp4','xmin'] = df['xmin']/4
df.loc[df['file'] ==  '2.mp4','xmin'] = df['xmin']/4
df.loc[df['file'] ==  '8.mp4','xmin'] = df['xmin']/4
df.loc[df['file'] ==  '10.mp4','xmin'] = df['xmin']/4
```

There is any option to do this in one line?

And this?

```
df.loc[df['file'] ==  '0.mp4','xmin'] = df['xmin']/4
df.loc[df['file'] ==  '2.mp4','xmin'] = df['xmin']/4
df.loc[df['file'] ==  '0.mp4','ymin'] = df['ymin']/4
df.loc[df['file'] ==  '2.mp4','ymin'] = df['ymin']/4
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df.loc[df['file'].isin(['0.mp4', '2.mp4', '8.mp4', '10.mp4']), 'xmin'] = df['xmin'] / 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check membership by `list` and also is possible simplify `= df['xmin']/4` to `/= 4`:

```
df.loc[df['file'].isin(['0.mp4','2.mp4','8.mp4','10.mp4']),'xmin'] /= 4
```